# First time programmer confused as to why the EditText and Button fields aren't going where I want them to

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am coding in XML on android studios, and I am having trouble getting the EditText to be centered at the top and the Button to be centered in the center. I do not know a lot about code so the other things I've read about Relative vs Linear Layout have been very confusing. I've never coded prior to this, so I'm very sorry if most of it is wrong.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/touch" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textSize="62sp"
    android:text="@string/begin_app"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make your linear layout orientation vertical, if you want to have one below the other. Maybe add a picture of what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code in your layout:

`android:layout_alignParentTop` will align the view on Top

`android:layout_alignParentTop` will align the view on center of parent

`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` will align the view in center of the parent

Layout code with `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In android studio just go to the layout xml file and **click Design**, you can drag and drop the widgets wherever you want and the system will generate the code for you with the placement you desired. Its great for starters.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I didn't know the code would adjust if I moved it in design, thank you!